# Where I can find BIG dataset

Tags: machine-learning, dataset, bigdata

I'm looking for a huge text classification datasets to apply what I learn in a Machine learning course. I'm looking for **wide data** and **tall data**. What I found till now are data between 200Mb up to 500Mb. Please is there any repo/url  where I can find dataset up to 2gb or more.

Answer (score 0):

You can find a good list of some publicly available datasets here : 
https://github.com/awesomedata/awesome-public-datasets

As per example, have a look at CommonCrawl Dataset https://commoncrawl.org/ which has been crawled from 25 billion web pages.
An index with the list of archives can be found here : http://index.commoncrawl.org/